# What weapons can a familiar use?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, familiars

If a familiar is nearly as smart as a human (or smarter than the average human, depending on the master's level), and many of them have a high Dexterity score, and familiars inherit all of the master's skills, can it be inferred that a familiar for whom it is physically possible to hold an object (for instance a hawk) can also use a weapon? If that's too much of a stretch, can it be given something like holy water or an acid bottle to drop or throw on the enemy?

What about a familiar that can obviously use a weapon (such as the Imp, which is stated as generally attacking with a shortsword)? What are its weapon proficiencies? Does it gain the same weapon proficiencies as its master? (Arguably not much for a Wizard, but already quite a few weapons if we're talking about a Sorcerer.)

Comment: Although it's not a particularly important detail, the typical [imp](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/devil.htm#imp) appears to favor its sting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Can a [familiar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm#familiars) hold an object?

Most can *somehow*. This will rely on the DM's generosity to some degree, but a familiar's ability to manipulate items physically should be on par with a similar real-life animal. This means, for example, having creatures carry items and drop them is well within most creatures' abilities if their Strengths allow. (Although I suggest wiping off an item before retrieving it yourself. Toad spit. Ew.)

#### Can a [familiar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm#familiars) wield a weapon?

A creature doesn't gain its master's weapon proficiencies when it becomes a familiar. A familiar's type is [magical beast](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#magicalBeastType), yet neither magical beasts nor [animals](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#animalType) gain weapon proficiencies beyond their natural weapons due to their types, so the creature will suffer a −4 penalty on attack rolls with any other weapons unless it somehow gains proficiency.

That said, even the Intelligence 15 hawk familiar of a level 20 wizard *probably* lacks the *physicality* to wield a weapon designed for humans effectively, and such a wizard's toad familiar almost certainly can't, but ask the DM. (I don't doubt that, for example, intelligent hawk *culture* would eventually develop appropriate weapons, but that's beyond this question's scope.)

#### Can an [improved familiar](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#improvedFamiliar) use weapons?

This is more complicated. Creature with appropriate manipulators *can* wield weapons, but whether a *particular* improved familiar can do so is up to the DM. However, an improved familiar with a type other than animal keeps its type, and, for example, [outsiders](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#outsiderType) are proficient with all simple and martial weapons, making an [imp](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/devil.htm#imp) with a sword a thing. Just be sure the sword's [sized appropriately](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#weaponSize).

Comment: I'm wondering... could I possibly give my Hawk (a Tiny-sized animal) a Tiny-sized long weapon like a pike and, no matter how clumsy it is with it, have it threaten an adjacent square for flanking purposes? Also, does a Celestial Hawk (which comes from another plane, and is thus an outsider, I think) have proficiency with all simple and martial weapons? If so, that's rather awesome.

Comment: @Ariane [Funny you should ask.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47227/8610)

Comment: Thanks. You were too quick though, you missed my second question in the edit.

Comment: Ah, I think I answered myself. A Celestial Hawk is not an Outsider, but an Extraplanar Magical Beast, therefore it gains no proficiency.