# Does a Tiny or smaller creature's charge trigger an attack of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, creature-size, charge

A Tiny or smaller creature that enter's an opponent's space, be it for attacking or anything else, usually triggers an attack of opportunity. But I don't think charges usually trigger an attack of opportunity from the defender. What about a charge from a Tiny or smaller creature, which needs to enter the opponent's square to complete its charge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, they would provoke an attack of opportunity for a charge attack against a creature with Reach: 5 feet.**

---

**Explanative Scenario**

The tiny, diminutive or fine creature makes its charge (against a small or larger creature), but then has to enter the opponents square to attack<sup>1</sup>, provokes an [attack of opportunity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/attacksOfOpportunity.htm), and is then allowed to make it's attack<sup>2</sup>.

---

**Explanative Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup>[Tiny, Diminutive and Fine Creatures](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm#bigandlittlecreaturesincombat)

> Creatures that take up less than 1 square of space typically have a natural reach of 0 feet, meaning they can’t reach into adjacent squares. They must enter an opponent’s square to attack in melee. This provokes an attack of opportunity from the opponent.

<sup>2</sup>[Attacking on a Charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge)

> After moving, you may make a single melee attack.

Comment: Thanks. It should be noted that by RAW, Tiny or smaller creatures don't have reach no matter what weapon they use (because 0 feet x 2 = 0 feet). See this answer: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/47338/14702